# How to ask for 627 fields to Marketo's APIs

Tags: endpoint, marketo

I am new in these type of access. I need to retrieve lead changes from Marketo, with about 627 attribute names. But the field list in the endpoint cannot be empty, and cannot contain such number of attributes.

Somebody know how to solve this? What is the maximum number of fields allowed in the endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

There's no explicit limit.  What are you encountering that makes you think you can't retrieve all of the fields?

Answer (score 0):

make sure to use POST and pass in _method="GET" as a parameter. If you use GET you will run into URL size limits when you specify that many fields.